# How to specify a specific column value to regress in Python?

Tags: python

I'm conducting some linear regressions using Python.  I have a fairly large data file I'm working with, and one of the columns I'm looking at is titled "male" which points to a the gender of a subject.  Column values can be 1 = male, 0 = female.  "rgroupx" is the treatment variable (0 = control, 6 = high status treatment) and "log_mm" is the outcome variable.

One of the questions I need to answer is: *How much does the high status treatment affect the number of traffic violations post intervention for male drivers? Is there a significant treatment effect for female drivers?*

I have below my current Python statement.  My problem is for both questions, how would I specify a column value to include in the regression?  If the question is asking for male drivers, how do I tell Python to include only 1s?  Thanks in advance!

```
model3 = smf.ols('log_mm ~ rgroupx + male', data=Traffic).fit()
```

Comment: It's not really clear from the information you've posted whether you should be splitting your data and conducting separate regressions for each gender, or looking for a statistical interaction between gender and treatment. These are statistical questions though, not programming ones, and you might be better off searching on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If the structure of your data is in a dataframe, than a combination of indexing and dropping data while assigning it to a new variable 'male' would work.

Example:

```
males_df = data.drop(data[data.gender != 1].index)
```

variable for regression:

```
males = males_df.gender
```